# Can't select a specific element in Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Im trying to scrape this page:

https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortment

I'm scraping almost all the links in each category section successfully. But for some reason, all those "More.." links are not going through, even though their Xpath should be the same as the other links.

[What I looked for in my inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXEFI.png)

What i'm currently doing is looking out for all the "href" values that belong to "a" tags with a class value `category-navigation--link`

I am using Scrapy, on Python, so the way I'm getting info from my script is:

```
response.xpath("//a[@class='category-navigation--link']/@href")
```

This worked well to give most of the links in the page, except for these "More.." links, but I can't see why. They seem to be the same as the others, yet the xpath selector somehow fails to get the information..

EDIT: Here is my code. It should be working just like the beautiful soup example PS1212 posted here, only difference is that im returning links. It misses all those urls in the href field from all those "More.." elements for some reason..

```
import scrapy
from ..items import CoolBlueItems


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "coolblue2"

    start_urls = ["https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortments]

    def __init__(self):

        self.declare_xpath()

    def declare_xpath(self):

        self.getAllSubCategoriesUrlsXpath = "//a[@class='category-navigation--link']/@href"

    def parse(self, response):

        item = CoolBlueItems()

        urls_list = []

        no_scrape_urls = ["/en/promotion", "/en/second-chance", "/en/gift-cards", "/en/coolblue-fan-products", "/en/all-brands"]

        for Urls in response.xpath(self.getAllSubCategoriesUrlsXpath).getall():

            current_url = Urls.strip()

            if current_url not in urls_list and current_url not in no_scrape_urls and current_url.count("/") == 2:
                urls_list.append(current_url)
                item["Url"] = response.urljoin(current_url)
                yield item
```

I followed PS1212 suggestion. Had to make some modifications because it was throwing an error related to the way information was being handled to the re. function:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import CoolBlueItems
    
    
    class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "coolblue2"
    
        start_urls = ["https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortments]

        for a in response.css("a.category-navigation--link::attr('href')").getall():
            item["Url"] = re.split('/', a)
            yield item
```

It still skips that element that i want. Here are the first entries of the output:

```
Category,CurrentPrice,OriginalPrice,Title,Url
,,,,",en,laptops"
,,,,",en,laptops,apple-macbook"
,,,,",en,desktops"
,,,,",en,monitors"
,,,,",en,keyboards"
```

EDIT: The problem was the selector itself. I can make my script work, but I'm still curious why the CSS selector is working and the xpath is not. Here is a test I have done, where i use xpath and css to scrape all the elements from sections "a" with a certain class:

```
>>> response.xpath("//a[@class='category-navigation--link']")[4].getall()
['<a class="category-navigation--link" href="/en/keyboards" rel="nofollow">\n                    Keyboards\n                </a>']
>>>



>>> response.css('a.category-navigation--link')[4].get()
'<a class="category-navigation--link category-navigation--link--black" href="/en/laptops-desktops-monitors" data-trackclickevent="Homepage categor
y navigation|Computers &amp; tablets|More..">\n                                                                        More..\n
                                                 </a>'
```

As you can see, the 5th element of the array, index 4 in both cases, returns different values. I must be doing a mistake somewhere in my Xpath selector..

Comment: Show us the code you're using, and the results you get.  Saying "It somehow fails fails to get the information" doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import Beatifulsoup

htl = requests.get('https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortment')
soup = Beautifulsoup(htl.text, 'lxml')

a_tages = soup.findAll('a', class_='category-navigation--link')
for a in a_tages:
       href_list = re.split('/',a.get('href')))
       print(href_list.pop())
```

Via Scrapy:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import CoolBlueItems

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = "coolblue2"
      start_urls = ["https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortments]

      def parse(self, response):
          item = CoolBlueItems()

          for a in response.css('a.category-navigation--link'):
              url = a.css("::attr('href')").extract()
              split_url = re.split('/', url))
              print(split_url.pop())
```

**output**:

```
laptops
apple-macbook
desktops
monitors
laptops-desktops-monitors
...
```

Comment: PS1212 answer works, that last line "laptops-desktops-monitors" is what i was missing, but i need to do it via scrapy.

Comment: Great! It will work with scrapy too. You just need to change the selector pattern according that.

Comment: Added my code in the post PS1212. I think it should work like yours, it just returns the urls instead.

Comment: @JumBê Just updated my answer for `scrapy` code too. Hope it solve your query.

Comment: Found some issues with its implementation, but i managed to make it work. It still returns the same as my xpath example. Was it because of the modifications i made? I updated the post with what i did

Comment: @JumBê You just need to pop the last element after regex.

Comment: I got it working now, with CSS. Thanks for the help! Anyway, I was kinda liking to use Xpath, it seems more intuitive to me than css. I believe they can do the same thing. I discovered that in this particular problem there is some issue with the selectors themselves. Please check my last edit.

Comment: Okay, great! Both in many ways good. Glad the answer helped you. Happy crawling!